# Mudar o valor do campo dinamicamente

Tags: javascript, ajax

Olá, gostaria de ajuda com meu código, eu queria que quando o usuário clicasse no campo com a lupa:

```
<a class="blue" href="#">
    <i class="ace-icon fa fa-search-plus bigger-130"></i>
</a>
```

O valor do campo status:
`<?php $status = $dados['status'];`

Mudasse, dinamicamente no banco de "N" para "S". Inicialmente o valor salvo para todas publicações é "N" mas eu quero que mude para "S", quando o usuário clicar.
Estou fazendo isso que é semelhante ao whatsapp; ao clicar fica como visualizado, mas é uma aplicação em PHP, um site.

Procurando vi que javascript e ajax já resolveriam isso, mas eu não sei como(vi também que onClick=function() já resolveria); eu montei um if para recuperar os valores depois com refresh.

```
<?php $status = $dados['status'];
        if  ($status == "N"){
            echo "<i class='ace-icon fa fa-circle red'></i>";}
        else if($status == "S"){
            echo "<i class='ace-icon fa fa-circle green'></i>"; 
} ?>
```

Comment: Dá uma pesquisada no site sobre ajax, tem bastante coisa e monta um teste, ai se reformula com uma dúvida pontual, assim está muito amplo...

Comment: muito ampla ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu faria isso usando jQuery. Fiz um [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dungahk/5dtbv43h/3/) que exemplifica como você deve implementar essa funcionalidade.

Basicamente você pega o evento de clique do elemento e faz uma chamada AJAX para a URL que fará a mudança no banco, nesse caso você precisará de um código simples em PHP para fazer isso. A seguir um exemplo de como seria, você teria que adaptar para o seu caso.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['status']) && isset($_POST['id'])) {
    $status = $_POST['status'];
    $id = $_POST['id'];

    // Atualiza no banco de dados
    $servername = 'localhost';
    $dbport = 123;
    $database = 'nome_db';
    $username = 'root';
    $password = 'senha123';

    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;port=$dbport;dbname=$database", $username, $password);
    $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE mensagem SET status='?' WHERE id='?'");
    $data = array($status, $id);

    if ($stmt->execute($data))
        echo '1'; // sucesso
    else
        echo '0'; // falha
} else {
    echo '0'; // falha
}
```